# Can we stick with TinyMCE 5 even though TinyMCE 6 has been released? And if so, for how long?

Tags: tinymce

My sites are set up and working fine with the free version TinyMCE 5 in the cloud. I guess it's their AWS.

Can we continue to use it even though version 6 was apparently released? If so, for how long? Do they leave their old versions up and available?

Right now I feel "if something's not broken don't fix it."

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE 5 will continue to work to past March 15, 2023 - You can see exactly which version in the TinyMCE 5 series is supported in the Tiny Docs page on Supported Versions. This way, you can plan out a timeline for migration: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/enterprise/system-requirements/#supportedtinymceversions

If you'd like to try TinyMCE 6 to see what it offers, the new documentation for TinyMCE 6 is also ready: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/

Migrating to TinyMCE 6 is straightforward – it involves adjusting the cdn script for accessing Tiny in the cloud, and then checking for Plugin and Option names that have been renamed in the transition from Tiny 5 to Tiny 6.  The Migration guide has all the information: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/6.0-release-notes-overview/#overview

Comment: Thanks. That's very useful. How do I know which version of 5 I'm running? Since it's the cloud version can I just assume it's the latest 5? Also, when it says "end of support" does that mean TinyMCE removes it from AWS and it no longer runs? Or just that they don't provide support for it any more?

Comment: I see you can just look at the source where tinymce is embedded, click on the cloud-based .js file and look at the source. According to that, my version is `majorVersion:"5",minorVersion:"10.3",releaseDate:"2022-02-09"`. According to the support page mentioned, end of support is still TBD, so I guess I don't have to worry about it yet.

Comment: Hi Doug, you're welcome, glad to help.

That is a good method to learn what version is running. As for the supported version point, when the support period ends, the version of TinyMCE is still available through the CDN link and remains running, but is not actively provided with support.

You can check on all the current versions available online through this link: https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/available-versions